# How to use a while loop to give percentage

Tags: python

I’m trying to make a system where, if you input a number, it tells you what grade it would be, but it doesn’t work.

My code is

```
percentage = input(“Please input a number”)
if percentage == 100:
     Grade = (“A*”)
     print (“A”)
elif percentage ==80:
     Grade = (“A”)
     print (“A”)
elif percentage == 60:
     Grade = (“B”)
     print (“B”)
elif percentage == 40:
     Grade = (“C”)
     print (“C”)
else:
     Grade == (“D”)
     print (“D”)
```

The error says

```
NameError: name ‘grade’ is not defined
```

Help, sorry in advance if I missed something obvious

Comment: `Grade == (“D”)` in your `else` section. That is a comparision and not an assignment operation.

Comment: Change Percentage to percentage in line one

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact error message? there is no variable named `'grade'` (lowercase, python is case-sensitive)

Comment: There are many syntax errors with this code. When comparing input strings with integers, you first need to cast the input to `int` with `percentage = int(input("Please input a number: "))`. Lastly, change `Grade == ("D")` from an equality test to assignment `Grade = ("D")`.

Comment: suggestion: the many `print`statements are unnecessary. just add one last line at the end: `print Grade`

Answer (score 0):

== and = are different operations. == is comparison while = is assignment.

Try the following code:

```
percentage = int(input("Please input a number"))
if percentage == 100:
     grade = "A*"
elif percentage == 80:
     grade = "A"
elif percentage == 60:
     grade = "B"
elif percentage == 40:
     grade = "C"
else:
     grade = "D"
print(grade)
```

Comment: This code just prints 'D' regardless of the input. Need to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Understood. Edited for the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The below code working in python2.7.

```
percentage = input("Please input a number")
if percentage == 100:
     Grade = ("A*")
     print ("A*")
elif percentage ==80:
     Grade = ("A")
     print ("A")
elif percentage == 60:
     Grade = ("B")
     print ("B")
elif percentage == 40:
     Grade = ("C")
     print ("C")
else:
     Grade = ("D")
     print ("D")
```

Comment: Unnecessary to assign `Grade` if you're just going to print what it references.

Answer (score 0):

Please learn about [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
percentage = int(input("Please input a number: "))
grade = ''

if percentage == 100:
     grade = "A*"     
elif percentage == 80:
     grade = "A"     
elif percentage == 60:
     grade = "B"     
elif percentage == 40:
     grade = "C"     
else:
     grade = "D"

print(grade)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things going on here.

1. Your input is a string, but you're comparing it to an int (always false).
2. You are only checking exact percentages, what about ranges? In your code, an input percent of 81 would result in a D grade, probably not the result you want for real-world input data.

Try something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict as od

CUTOFFS = od()
CUTOFFS[100.0] = 'A*'
CUTOFFS[80.0] = 'A'
CUTOFFS[60.0] = 'B'
CUTOFFS[40.0] = 'C'
CUTOFFS[0.0] = 'D'

def percent_to_grade(p):
    for k, v in CUTOFFS.items():
        if k <= float(p):
            return v
    raise ValueError('Invalid CUTOFFS data')

def get_grade(percent=None):
    while True:
        if percent is not None:
            try:
                percent = float(percent)
                if percent < 0.0 or percent > 100.0:
                    percent = None
                    raise ValueError('Invalid value for percent')
                break
            except Exception as exc:
                print str(exc), 'Trying again ...'
        percent = input('What is your grade? ')
    ##
    grade = percent_to_grade(percent)
    return grade

def test():
    vals = [100, 80, 79.9, 39, 0, -2, 'TBD', None]
    for v in vals:
        print v, get_grade(v)
        print
```

Run the `test` function to see this in action:

```
>>> test()
100 A*

80 A

79.9 B

39 D

0 D

-2 Invalid value for percent Trying again ...
What is your grade? 10
D

TBD could not convert string to float: TBD Trying again ...
What is your grade? 20
D

None What is your grade? 30
D
```

I gave manual input to the last three so we could see all test cases.